# Connecting points in a map

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I have $x + 1$ points that are connected by $x$ number of routes. Any pair of points has at most 1 route between them. We can assume $x$ is any positive integer.

How do I prove that there's at least one point that has a route to at most one other point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every point we are going to add how many routes it is connected to, and we are going to add all those numbers. We are going to get $2x$ as a result because each rout increases the sum by $2$ (one for each endpoint).

Since the sum of the degrees of the $x+1$ points is $2x$ it is impossible for all of them to be greater than or equal to $2$ (because otherwise the sum would be at least $2x+2$). It follows at least one of those integers is less than $2$, which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: when you say the sum of the non-negative integers do you really mean the sum of the degrees of each point?

Comment: yes but I was assuming you didn't know what that was

Comment: i've been drawing points and i found that when i draw 4 points (and thus 3 edges), there are 2 points which have a degree of 1. the proof states that there's at least 1 point (not two). am i missing something?

Comment: at least one point means any number other than $0$ is good. I think you meant to type "and thus 3 routes (or edges). Because a vertex and a point is the same thing colloquially

Comment: vertices are also called points and routes are also called edges.

Comment: thanks for catching! fixed